# Selecting Which Argument to Pass Dynamically in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to pass a specific argument dynamically to a function, where the function has default values for most or all arguments.

Here's a toy example:

```
library(data.table)
mydat <- data.table(evildeeds=rep(c("All","Lots","Some","None"),4),
                    capitalsins=rep(c("All", "Kinda","Not_really", "Virginal"),
                    each = 4),
                    hellprobability=seq(1, 0, length.out = 16))

hellraiser <- function(arg1 = "All", arg2= "All "){
    mydat[(evildeeds %in% arg1) & (capitalsins %in% arg2), hellprobability]}

hellraiser()

hellraiser(arg1 = "Some")

whicharg = "arg1"
whichval = "Some"

#Could not get this to work:
hellraiser(eval(paste0(whicharg, '=', whichval)))
```

I would love a way to specify dynamically which argument I'm calling: In other words, get the same result as `hellraiser(arg1="Some")` but while picking whether to send arg1 **OR** arg2 dynamically. The goal is to be able to call the function with only one parameter specified, and specify it dynamically.

Comment: And yes, I know I can give all args default values, then switch some custom value upon one of them, then do the function call, but I'd like to just do it in one go.

Comment: PS: I'm guessing it's some do.call thing ... ? Never had to use it before, so I could use some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the result with

```
hellraiser(eval(parse(text=paste(whicharg, ' = \"', whichval, '\"', sep=''))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! I'll wait a bit to see if there's a more straightforward way forthcoming, and otherwise I'll accept it as canonical.

Comment: You could always write a function that takes in a list of length-2 vectors that corresponds to the 'argument', 'value' scheme, use the above paste command on each of them, and then collapse them with a ', '. I can edit that in my answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some form of `do.call` like

```
do.call("hellraiser", setNames(list(whichval), whicharg))
```

but really this just seems like a bad way to handle arguments for your functions. It might be better to treat your parameters like a list that you can more easily manipulate. Here's a version that allows you to choose values where the argument names are treated like column names

```
hellraiser2 <- function(..., .dots=list()) {
    dots <- c(.dots, list(...))
    expr <- lapply(names(dots), function(x) bquote(.(as.name(x)) %in% .(dots[[x]])))
    expr <- Reduce(function(a,b) bquote(.(a) & .(b)), expr)
    eval(bquote(mydat[.(expr), hellprobability]))
}

hellraiser2(evildeeds="Some", capitalsins=c("Kinda","Not_really"))
hellraiser2(.dots=list(evildeeds="Some", capitalsins=c("Kinda","Not_really")))
```

This use of `...` and `.dots=` syntax is borrowed from the `dplyr` standard evaluation functions.

Comment: Thanks! This works great for the toy example, but only if I pass it both arguments, which is what I was trying to avoid! Moreover, it's a bit different in my *actual* use case (some args in a reactive shiny function), but I'll look into it (it may take me a while to understand ***why*** this code works).